# Magento2 Mixins: How to write a requirejs-config.js?

Tags: magento2, mixins

What exactly do I need to add to the `requirejs-config.js` for adding a mixin?

The Magento documentation has an example of this, but I seem to lack some basic understanding of javascript and frontend development.

```
var config = {
 config: {
     mixins: {
         'Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns': {
             'OrangeCompany_Sample/js/columns-mixin': true
         },
         "Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal": {
             "OrangeCompany_Sample/js/modal-widget-mixin": true
         }
     }
 }
};
```

Why, for example, is it `Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns`? It seems to refer to the file `src/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/controls/columns.js` (this is the path with composer).

The text `js/grid/controls/columns` matches between file name and `requirejs`. `Magento_Ui` is the extension name. Does it mean, this is the syntax?

```
Syntax:
<module name>/<path of file in module>/<filename without extension>
```

Or is there any other way to determine; another logic?
I have the same question for the next line (`OrangeCompany_Sample/js/modal-widget-mixin`). Same syntax?

My specific case seems to have an additional hurdle: Most of the extensions are installed via composer and therefore in the `vendor` directory. But a handful of the 3rd party extensions is not able to use *composer* and therefore lives in `app/code/<3rdparty>`. Playing around with the paths in the `requirejs-config.js` file, I am able to address javascript files in the *vendor* folder, but not those in the `app/code/...` folder.

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly do I need to add to the requirejs-config.js for adding a mixin?

1. In theme - app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/requirejs-config.js
2. In module - app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js